# wso2ei 6.6 scheduler gets stopped automatically

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using `WSO2 EI 6.6.0`, sometimes the following task gets stopped automatically and it starts working again only after a restart. No error found in the logs. The task which I am using is a `injectTo` proxy service.

Please find the task configurations given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Bank_Invoice_plan_out_xml_Task" class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz">
   <trigger interval="5" />
   <property xmlns:task="wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
      <Input>Start</Input>
   </property>
   <property xmlns:task="wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="proxyName" value="Bank_Invoice_plan_out_xml" />
   <property xmlns:task="wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="injectTo" value="proxy" />
</task>
```

Comment: Can you add more information about setup this task?

Comment: please find the my task configuration.I have placed it in tasks folder which is inside default folder.

Comment: <task xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Bank_Invoice_plan_out_xml_Task"
     class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
        group="synapse.simple.quartz"><trigger interval="5" /><property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message"><Input>Start</Input></property><property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="proxyName"  value="Bank_Invoice_plan_out_xml"/><property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"         
               name="injectTo"
               value="proxy"/></task>